# Object.getOwnPropertyNames Function (JavaScript) from this data it does'nt work

Tags: javascript

i am having trouble to get object property name from this data that i retrieve from some API server :

```
var arrData = [{"data":
{"plmn":"Voda","id":"B193","time":1499257121817,"cell":{"rsrp":
[-132.5,-108.88],"rsrq":[-18.69,-6.56],"earfcn":1550,"pci":454,"celltiming":    
[252],"sinr":-12.8,10.7]},"mac":"9C65F9"},"time":1499282331405,
},{"data":
{"plmn":"Voda","rssi":-106,"id":"4179","time":315939662698,"cells":
[{"sc":453,"ecno":-19.53,"r99":"intraMon","rscp":-125.53,"ch":10837},
{"sc":452,"ecno":-13.97,"r99":"active","rscp":-119.97,"ch":10837},
{"sc":452,"ecno":-19.53,"r99":"active","rscp":-125.53,"ch":10812},
{"sc":453,"ecno":-19.37,"r99":"intra","rscp":-125.37,"ch":10812}],"mac":
"9C65F9211012"},"time":1499282452590,"deviceID":"9C65F9211012"}]
```

i already try with this code :

```
var collectField = [];

 for (var prop in arrData) {
    if (arrData.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
       collectField.push(prop);
    }
 }

// and still wrong Outputs: [0,1,2,3.....]

 console.log(collectField);
```

the output result that i expected :

```
[plmn,id,time,cell,,ecno,cells,rscp..and all of that object field]
```

hope someone can help this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please add valid data.

Comment: the json is not valid

Comment: what about `cell` vs `cells`?

Comment: that is already real data i copy paste here Nina Scholz. The data coming so dinamyc

Comment: Try pasting it [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=format+json&atb=v37-2bq&ia=answer). It will show the syntax errors.

Comment: Yap..there is object cell, and cells, and each other have a different data contain

Comment: ?? You've iterating an array, and array has numbered indices, hence the output is exactly what you can expect. You never access the objects inside the array, how would you expect to get some property names from the objects then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for-in` construct doesn't retrieve the object from array but it's index. So you're trying to access `hasOwnProperty` on the number. First you need to access array member and then property eg. like this:

```
for (var index in arrData) {
  var obj = arrData[index];
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    collectField.push(obj[prop]);
  }
}
```

Comment: nice, you supply a solution for a questionable data structure.